# magento this letter cannot be sent for particular mail only

Tags: magento, email

Hi programatically i add mail in magento. Default mail system works well. but my mail through this bug.

```
2013-10-08T05:06:17+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.' in /home/domain/public_html/fashion/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:398
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mall140/public_html/fashion/app/code/local/seller/Marketplaceseller/controllers/SendmailController.php(18): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send('amia.1901@...', 'victor', Array)
#1 /home/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Webkul_Marketplacepartner_SendmailController->indexAction()
#2 /home/fashion/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#3 /home/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /home/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /home/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

This is error code. please help me

Comment: can u share your email code?

Comment: edit your question to add `Webkul_Marketplacepartner_SendmailController::indexAction()`'s code

Answer (score 5):

This exception means `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::isValidForSend()` returned `false`:

```
public function isValidForSend()
{
    return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

Without seeing the code setting up your email template before sending it's hard to say which of the four conditions fails.

My wild guess would be that SMTP mails are disabled in your backend.

Check whether `System -> Configuration -> System -> Mail sending settings -> Disable Email Communications` is set to "No".

Comment: I had this problem too, I didn't have sender email, however Magento log error is vague, it should tell that I cannot send emails, because sender email is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error during calling `sendTransactional()` function. I was thinking that there is some issue in email template in subject. To find exact issue as mentioned by Jurgen Thalen in his answer I inspected `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::isValidForSend()` function like below

```
public function isValidForSend()
{
    //remove this after checking, never change core files
    Mage::log("Sender Name:".$this->getSenderName());
    Mage::log("Sender email:".$this->getSenderEmail());
    Mage::log("Template subject:".$this->getTemplateSubject());
    Mage::log("Email disabled:".Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable'));

    return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

Now check your `system.log` for me template subject was coming fine but sender name and sender email was not coming.

Below was my code:

```
sendTransactional(
        $template,
        "myemail@gmail.com",
        $recipient['email'],
        $recipient['name'],
        array(
                'myvar1'  => $myvar1,
                'myvar2' => $myvar2,
                'myvar3' =>$myvar3,
                'myvar4' =>$myvar4 
        )
   )
```

Below is send transaction function in core file:

```
/**
    * Send transactional email to recipient
    *
    * @param   int $templateId
    * @param   string|array $sender sneder informatio, can be declared as part of config path
    * @param   string $email recipient email
    * @param   string $name recipient name
    * @param   array $vars varianles which can be used in template
    * @param   int|null $storeId
    * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
    */
   public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null)
```

As you can see second parameter $sender should be String or array, as I was passing string but was not accepting.

I changed my `sendTransactional()` like below: second parameter passing as array

```
sendTransactional(
        $template,
        array(
                'email' => "myemail@gmail.com",
                'name' => "satish sojitra",
            ),
        $recipient['email'],
        $recipient['name'],
        array(
                'myvar1'  => $myvar1,
                'myvar2' => $myvar2,
                'myvar3' =>$myvar3,
                'myvar4' =>$myvar4 
        )
        )
```

It works like charm! Don't forget to remove `Mage::log` statements from core files.

Below is complete code snippet to send transactional email

```
$translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    //@var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate 
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

    $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
    //add bcc
    $mailTemplate->addBcc("bccemail@gmail.com");//accept array also

    //add cc: $Cc_email_ids can be array or string
    $mailTemplate->getMail()->addCc($Cc_email_ids);//accept array also
    /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
    //template path
    $templateConfigPath = "configuration/product_settings/failure_template";

    $template = Mage::getStoreConfig($templateConfigPath, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

    $to = array(
            array("email"=> "to_1@gmail.com","name"=>"to_name"),
            array("email"=> "to_2@gmail.com","name"=>"to_name")
        );

    $sendTo = array();
    foreach ($to as $recipient)
    {
        if (is_array($recipient))
        {
            $sendTo[] = $recipient;
        }
        else
        {
            $sendTo[] = array(
                'email' => $recipient,
                'name' => null,
            );
        }
    }

    $myvar1 = 0;
    $myvar2 = 0;
    $myvar3 = 0;
    $myvar4 = "transactional email testing";
    foreach ($sendTo as $recipient) {
        $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()))
        ->sendTransactional(
        $template,
        array(
                'email' => "myemail@gmail.com",
                'name' => "satish sojitra",
            ),
        $recipient['email'],
        $recipient['name'],
        array(
                'myvar1'  => $myvar1,
            'myvar2' => $myvar2,
            'myvar3' =>$myvar3,
            'myvar4' =>$myvar4
        )
        );
    }

  $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is like following

```
$emailTemplate->sendTransactional($emailTemplateId, $sender, $emailAddress, $name, $data, $store);
```

and Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::isValidForSend() returned false. Then most probabbly you are not passing sender information correct.

Check *app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php*

```
/**
 * Send transactional email to recipient
 *
 * @param   int $templateId
 * @param   string|array $sender sender information, can be declared as part of config path
 * @param   string $email recipient email
 * @param   string $name recipient name
 * @param   array $vars variables which can be used in template
 * @param   int|null $storeId
 *
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 *
 * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
 */
public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null)
```

Pass sender data as an array

```
        $sender = array(
            'name' => $fromEmail,
            'email' => $fromName
        );
        $emailTemplate->sendTransactional($emailTemplateId, $sender, $emailAddress, $fullName, $data, $store);
```

then after check if it works.