# Magento 1.9.1.1 mails are not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9.1.1 for my web application. The mails are not working like register, Forgot Password and order mails. I have enabled cron jobs. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Heve you checked errors logs ?

Comment: Hi Armen, Yes checked..No errors regarding mail issue

Comment: Try to check if logging is enabled in magneto like this ? - https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/kbase/magento/how-to-enable-error-and-exception-logging-in-magento.html, also have you configured emailing in magento admin console ?

Comment: I am getting this error in exception.log file. exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.'

Comment: Try to check this StackOverflow thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239879/magento-this-letter-cannot-be-sent-for-particular-mail-only

Comment: I have enable email.log. I am getting the following line.2015-12-12T08:25:04+00:00 DEBUG (7): true;'Owner';'owner@mysite.com';NULL
I can't understand.. Couldy ou please explain?

Comment: Seems it can be related nigher to additional modules nigher to something else related to configuration, my suggestion to recheck if all from this article first answer done from your side (like caching etc ..) - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15482/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-magento-1-7 and if it not solved then try to create more detailed ticket here (with errors which you get) - http://magento.stackexchange.com/ as there are more magneto specialists are present